# Find number of elements in a Circular Queue

Tags: queue, circular-list

How do I find the number of items in a circular queue?
|front - rear| doesn't always work.

Is there one formula to know how many elements are there in a circular queue using front, rear and size of the array?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What's wrong with traversing the queue until you get back to the start, counting the elements as you go?

Comment: which language? which library?

Answer (score 8):

actually the size would be,

```
size = front > rear ? (MAX - front + rear + 1) : (rear - front + 1);
```

or one can go for a generic formula:

```
size = abs(abs(MAX - front) - abs(MAX -rear));//this works in every situation
```

Comment: The generic formula is incorrect. Does not work for both when head>tail nor tail>=head. That aside, by definition of circular queue (MAX >= front, rear), putting absolute value for MAX-front and MAX-rear is unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you implement it using an array with size `N` so there are pointers pointing to the front and rear. Use the following formula:

```
size = front > rear ? (front - rear) : (front+N -  rear);
```

Comment: This gives `N` when `front == rear`.

Answer (score 3):

```
 Pointer1 = head; // (your node)
 count = 0;


 if( Pointer1 != NULL )
 {
   count = 1;
   Pointer2 = Pointer1->Next;
   while ( Pointer2 != NULL && Pointer2 != Pointer1 )
   {
     count++;
     Pointer2 = Pointer2->Next;
   }
 }

 return count;
```

Comment: Sorry the formatting is off - I'm new to this. The 'count = 0;' should be on a separate line, as should the nested if statement lines...

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using array of size N for queue implementation, then size of queue would be
`size = (N-front + rear) mod N`.

Comment: can you explain it ?

Comment: This is wrong. Does not work for ciircular queue. Take any example where f>r. This formula gives wrong results.

Answer (score 1):

The standard answer is to take two iterators at the beginning, increment the first one once, and the second one twice. 
Check to see if they point to the same object. Then repeat until the one that is incrementing twice either hits the first one or reaches the end. inside this loop use the counter to get the length of the CQuueeue

Comment: Or otherwise known as Floyd's cycle detection routine.

Answer (score 1):

None of the formulas take into account the empty (zero) case.  This will give you the number of free bytes available in the queue:

```
FreeSpace = (printRdQue == printWrQue) ? PRINT_QUEUE_SIZE :
           (PRINT_QUEUE_SIZE - printWrQue + printRdQue) % PRINT_QUEUE_SIZE;
```

Answer (score 0):

can your queue contain the same element in more than one location?  if it can then I don't think you can do this as there is no way to know the difference between:

a->b->c

and

a->b->c->a->b->c

if it can't contain the same element more than once, just look through the queue until you find an element you have already seen

Answer (score 0):

No of items in Circular queue is,

```
size = (N-f+r) mod N
```

where

- N is the size of array used in circular fashion
- f index of the front element
- r index immediately past the rear element

This formula work for both liner and circular queues.

Comment: Can you explain how this was derived ?

Comment: this will also return 0 when the queue is full and should return N

Comment: In a circular array having capacity as 12 , and r = 1 , f=3, your formula gives 10 , i think there should be a +1

Answer (score 0):

```
int lenghtQueue(queue* q){

     int len =0 ;
     if (isEmpty(q))
            return 0 ;

      queue* qe = q->next ;
      len ++ ;

       while(qe!=q){
             len ++ ;
             qe=qe->next ;           
       }
           return len ;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

if (Cqueue_front>Cqueue_rear)
            cout<<" The number of queue items are : "<

Comment: please put a little description.

Answer (score 0):

What do you need to implement a circular queue ?

Answer: you will need front and rear nodes + list of items + count_items.

Of course it is only implemented like this when the queue is finite, when talking about

dynamic allocation it will be different.

Take a look at an example in C Language,

```
typedef struct
{

TYPE items[MAXSIZE];

TYPE front;

TYPE rear;

int count_items;

} QUEUE;
```

This will assure you the exact amount of items are currently exist in the queue.

When you want to insert an item to the queue, you will simply increment rear and count_items, and when you want to remove an item from the queue, you will simply decrement rear and count_items.

Answer (score 0):

no. of elements = (rear + MAX_SIZE - front) % MAX_SIZE + 1

Answer (score 0):

The  easiest way to count the number of elements in the circular queue is:

if `front > rear`(i.e. front is ahead than rear)
Just count the number of empty spaces in between

```
front - (rear+1)
```

else if `front < rear`:

```
rear - front + 1
```

A C program if you need to:

```
    int find_ele(int total,int front,int rear){
         if(rear < front ) {  \\1st case
int res =    front - rear + 1;
return (total-res);}

else{
      return (rear - front + 1);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have are implementing a queue using a circular array A[0, n-1], where the (n-1)th index used to store the full/empty condition, the formula would be:

Number of elements = { rear-front + 1 , if rear==front

```
                 { rear-front + n , otherwise
```

We'll be moving the queue clockwise at each enqueue or dequeue.

Answer (score 0):

```
return (!isEmpty()   ? (m_front>m_rear) ? (m_capacity + m_rear - m_front) + 1 : m_rear - m_front + 1 : (m_rear - m_front));
enter code here
```

Comment: Here m_capacity is actual size of the queue.