# Circular queue size

Tags: pointers, size, circular-buffer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to find number of elements in a Circular Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459141/how-to-find-number-of-elements-in-a-circular-queue)

I am implementing a circular queue but I can't get the queue's size correctly.
I found a previous topic concerning the same problem and the solution proposed was to use two pointers and to increment the second one while it does not point to the same object as the first one. But I think this appoach can only work when there are different objects in the queue. In my case, all the object are similar. how can I get the size of the circular queue? 
This formula doesn't work for me too:

```
int size = abs(m_front -m_tail) ;
```

Where m_front and m_tail are the tail and front queue indexes.

Thanks

Comment: Q: is your queue implemented as an array?  If it's just a linked list, then the best you can do is determine when front == tail; you *cannot* determine "size" unless you keep the count yourself.

Comment: Same one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459141/how-to-find-number-of-elements-in-a-circular-queue

Comment: @paulsm4 : yes, it's implemented as an array. When front==tail, it just means that the array is empty.

Comment: @ KingsIndian : yes, it's the same question , this is the topic I am talking about in my message

Comment: @user16841 Right. You have to explain why those answers don't work for you. Why the object types stored concerns you? The pointers are for the queue itself, not to the objects stored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
if m_front > m_tail 
    size = (m_front - m_tail)
else
    size = (m_front + N - m_tail)
```

Where N is the length of your array.

Alternatively, you can just keep track of it yourself by incrementing a counter when you `Queue()`, and decrementing it when you `Dequeue()`.

Comment: Note that with only a head and tail index, you have no way of determining whether the list is empty or full if you allow all `N` places to be filled.  The best solution for speed is to prevent the last position from being filled, whereas the best solution for storage is to maintain either an `empty` or `full` flag during the Push and Pop operations.

Comment: thanks for your replies. I don't know why but the formula above doesn't work: it gives me always a result of zero.... Concerning your second proposition, won't this procedure create an access race when we try to increment and decrement the queue size at the ame time ( enqueue and dequeuerun in parallel) ??

Comment: If you're using threads, you should surround this (and your queue/dequeue methods) with locks using the same lock object.